# AWS SAM - Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-sam

AWS SAM deploying codebase to AWS cloud using aws-sam-cli but it throw me below error.

`Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_IAM]`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When you're creating or deploying a stack you need to explicitly allow creation of IAM resources. To do that, you need to add the parameter when calling `sam deploy`:

`--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`

If you want to create named IAM resources (e.g. roles or users where you explicitly specify the name), you'll want to use `--capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM` instead.

You can read more about deploying IAM resources in CloudFormation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-template.html#using-iam-capabilities

SAM deployment documentation: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/blob/develop/docs/deploying_serverless_applications.rst#deploying-your-application

Comment: thanks its work fine with `--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM` flag

Comment: thanks Could SAM be anymore opiniated ;(

Comment: Ok, 'funny' this didn't work for me:

`sam deploy --config-env default --profile myprofile –-capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`

But this did:

`sam deploy --config-env default --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --profile myprofile`

Answer (score 2):

Do check your YAML file indentation. review the YAML file once again, if it's a tad bit not up to the SAM standards it will throw this error. DO check once again.

Answer (score 1):

Search the stack in cloudformation and delete it, and then try to run the command again, this helped me solve the problem